# Base64 class missing from org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util eclipse Maven Webapp project

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

[image: Kindly find screenshot taken from eclipse]

Any Help !!! I know there are many alternatives but kinda confused why its being excluded now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been removed in favor of `java.util.Base64`. See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/pull/3829 and https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/commit/eafb9bdcb82dfa3fd76dd957d307b99d4a22c87f#diff-7174dd9761bb93b4295a4528a18878a0.

Comment: Thanks for your help !!! Thats the reason I shifted to Java Base64 from java util.